# Limit of an integral, with variable limits of integration

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Is there any way to simplify something like this in general?

$$\lim_{x \to C} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,y) \, dy$$

The specific integral I am trying to calculate is

$$ \lim_{R \to 0} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}R} \sqrt{\frac{R^2-2(t+R/\sqrt{2})^2}{R^2-(t+R/\sqrt{2})^2}} \, dt ,$$

although I think this might have some other issues associated with it.

Comment: You could try setting $t=Rx$ then simplifying the $R$'s in the integral; the $R$ in the upper limit should disappear, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $t=\sqrt{2}Ru$ to remove the dependence on $R$ from the limits, and then everything under the square root has an $R^2$ in it, so the integral reduces to
$$ \sqrt{2}R \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{R^2-2(\sqrt{2}Ru+R/\sqrt{2})^2}{R^2-(\sqrt{2}Ru+R/\sqrt{2})^2}} \, du = \sqrt{2}R \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-2(\sqrt{2}u+1/\sqrt{2})^2}{1-(\sqrt{2}u+1/\sqrt{2})^2}} \, du $$
Since the integral converges (the denominator is a difference of squares, so it has two unequal roots, and reciprocals of square roots are integrable, even if there are simple roots in the interval of integration), the limit is zero.